# How to display ``` in knitr chunks?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm generating a knitr (focusing on .Rmd files) manual for a project and wanted to embed a code chunk that actually displays the " ``` " marks as well as the internal chunk syntax. E.g.

````
``` {r sample, eval= FALSE}

Code example

```
````

So basically the exact visual you see above. Any thoughts on how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this by using four spaces before your code as follows:

So this:

[image]

Becomes this:

[image]

There also is this [SO-meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/82718/how-do-i-escape-a-backtick-in-markdown) discussion on how to escape this backtick in Markdown

Comment: Thanks for the etiquette tip - new to stackexchange.

Answer (score 3):

If you mean how to display the three backticks, the answer is "indent by 4 spaces" (see Pandoc's [four-space rule](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#the-four-space-rule))". If you mean how to display a literal **knitr** code chunk, the answer has been given by [**knitr** FAQ #8](https://github.com/yihui/knitr/blob/master/FAQ.md).